# Custom Domain for Tumblr

Tags: dns, subdomain, tumblr

I am trying to set up a custom domain for my tumblr account.

http://blog.scribeair.com/ to http://scribeair.tumblr.com

Can some one help me how to set up the DNS records for the subdomain.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a cname in your dns record so that blog.scribeair.com references scribeair.tumblr.com

More here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record

Comment: i am getting an error doing so.. updated the question

Comment: So set the first box to be blog and the second one to be scribeair.tumblr.com

Answer (score 3):

Setup blog.scribeair.com as an A-record pointing toward 72.32.231.8. Use http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains as a reference.

Comment: i am getting an error i tried doing that